# Is "am einmaligsten" a valid superlative

Tags: adjective, comparative

I found someone writing

> Der einmaligste Kuchen, den du jemals gesehen hast.

For me as a German this sounds strange. Is there really a comparative or even a superlative for `einmalig`? I mean, either something is unique or something is not. Imho, there isn't anything "uniquer" than any other thing.

(ah and maybe someone with enough reps wants to create some tags for `comparative` and `superlative`?)

Comment: Du hast dir die Frage schon selbst beantwortet: Nichts kann noch einmaliger sein als eine andere einmalige Sache. Das Adjektiv _einmalig_ ist nicht steigerbar.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich das war ja meine Frage, ob ich richtig liege, dass das völler Quatsch ist :D - aber danke

Comment: Das ist genauso falsch wie "einstigster", bzw. "einstigste" welches man recht oft hört.

Comment: Mir scheint es so, dass dieses Wort zwei bedeutungen hat. Einmalig, im Sinne von "unwiederholbar", kann nicht steigerbar sein, wie wir alle schon wissen. Was ist mit "einmalig" im Sinne von "phänomenal"?

Comment: I've heard "am einmaligsten" or "am einzigstartigsten" used mostly ironically but also sometimes unironically. I think the "sten" should be seen as _intensifying suffix_ instead of a superlative modifier. Like the "aller" prefix in "das Allerbeste" ("the very best") which doesn't really make sense as superlative (there can't be anything better than the best) but is used frequently.

Comment: It´s the same as with colors. Even in advertisement you hear things like: *Das weißeste weiß*, which is technically bullsh**

Comment: @Daniel Nope, it isn't. Whiteness is the albedo, the degree of reflectance. Fresh, undisturbed snow is e.g. whiter than clouds. *Das weißeste Weiß* is simply the white with the highest reflectance which is AFAIK titan dioxide.

Comment: @Thorsten: You are confusing two things here. Whiteness -> Weißegrade is a separate German word. You can say *Der Weißegrad des Schnees is höher als der der Wolken* That does not mean it is technically correct to say *Der Schnee ist weißer*

Comment: @Daniel No, using comparative and superlative for colors are known and used in German, I am a native who is also living in Hamburg. *Wolken sind weiß, Schnee ist weißer als Wolken und Titandioxid ist am weißesten* is a correct sentence. German also uses it e.g. in idioms: *Des Nachbarn Gras ist immer grüner.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The form is constructed according to the normal way of forming superlatives, and you immediately recognized it as such. I'd say this means that the intent of the speaker came across to you load and clear, so we have no choice but to accept that someone formed a superlative for "einmalig" and you understood it.

That doesn't mean that it's in any way useful, "reasonable" or "correct" to do this - there could be any number of prescriptions "prohibiting" it. In this case, obviously it's unnecessary to form superlatives for a property that is incomparable by definition. But just as anti-theft laws don't actually prohibit theft, anti-nonsense rules don't actually prevent nonsense from being said.  The question whether this sentence "really" contains a superlative or not is therefore down to definitions.

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes when they speak. So whoever wrote "Der einmaligste Kuchen" might just have been distracted or tired. The only way to know if it's grammatical in *that person's German* is to go and ask, "what do you think of this sentence? Is it grammatical?" Then s/he might say yes, and might say no. But that's still only one grammaticality judgement, one person's opinion.

Comment: @Wilson German has a (semi-)official source of truth, though, the Duden. Unlike with English, there is no such thing as *that person's German*. Words that are in common use may be added, but grammatical rules are not so easily changed. The Duden even contains rules that appear in dialects which might be ungrammatical in High German.

Comment: In my language we commonly say "most optimal solution", "a bigger half", "more unique product". In math it's a nonsense, in but in common speech it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Graipher The Duden allows "Pizzas" too since some time, so I - just personally - don't put too much trust into that "truth". ;D

Answer (score 7):

It isn't a superlativ, it is a [Hyperlativ](https://punkt-und-komma.net/lektorat/hyperlativ-was-ist-das).

While people knowing German grammar will balk at its usage, *it is used*, mostly for

- a hypothetical thing which is impossible because it combines advantages without disadvantages: "Das optimalste Farmtier wäre die eierlegende Wollmilchsau."
- a thing which is so fantastically good that it dwarfs other things, so you adjust the language to show your enthusiasm: "Das ist der einmaligste Kuchen, den ich je gegessen habe" (Die bisherigen Kuchen waren kein Vergleich).